# How to find Planet Position using skyfield

Tags: python, skyfield

I want to find planet position using skyfield in the form of
Ecliptic longitude,latitude, speed and distance in geocentric

Comment: There are some documentation here https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/positions.html#positions-and-coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to go ahead and read the Skyfield documentation — have you made it very far yet, or are you still at the beginning? One of its earliest sections is its Examples:

https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/examples.html

By searching that web page for concepts you are interested in, you can sometimes skip reading the full documentation — for example, try searching for the phrase “ecliptic longitude” and you’ll find an example where it’s computed for the Moon.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure that you realize that you're asking a very difficult question.  The motions of the planets are not simple ellipses.  How much precision do you need?  Are you asking for a program that will work for this year, for this decade, for this century?

A good **introduction** can be found [here](http://www.stjarnhimlen.se/comp/tutorial.html).  For more information, you really need to take a course on planetary dynamics.  I believe that NASA has some Fortran code (the SPICE kernel) that is used for their spacecraft.